# SQL : selecting the table values of table from @variable like 'Select * from @Table_name' where @table_name=[DB_Name].[Schema_name].[table_name]

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there any way to achieve this functionality with SQL?

Actually I am creating a variable `@table_name` and in that variable I am storing the `[DB_Name].[Schema_name].[table_name]` dynamically which means I am using while loop and for every loop run, the `@table_name` value will change based on the condition.

So within the loop, I should get a result for below query

```
select * 
from @table_name
```

where `@table_name` value will be dynamic like

```
set @table_name = [stagingdb].[emp].[employee]
```

This should result in a query like this:

```
select * from @table_name;

empid  | empnm
-------+-------
1      | Steve
2      | Ram
```

In the second run:

```
set @table_name = [stagingdb].[stdt].[student]
```

This should return a result like:

```
select * from @table_name;

studid  | student_nm
--------+-------------
1       | Naina
2       | Henry
```

Hope it is understandable and you will help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DQE (dynamic query execution) to solve this problem.

With DQE you can create your command with string operations like `concat` and execute that.

For example

```
declare @tableName nvarchar(100) = 'My Table Name'
declare @command nvarchar(max) = 'select * from ' + @tableName 
exec(@command)
```

After this section you can change this code for loop iteration and create your
command per rotation

More examples and references

- [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [mssqltips](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/)
- [sqlservertutorial](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-stored-procedures/sql-server-dynamic-sql/)
- [sqlshack](https://www.sqlshack.com/dynamic-sql-in-sql-server/#:%7E:text=Executing%20dynamic%20SQL%20using%20sp_executesql,parameters%20used%20in%20the%20query.)

These tips solve your problem but this work isn't good if you wants to find record count of all table for example. Be careful when using DQE.

Comment: @marc_s i change my answer and write full name

Comment: Tip: The best practice when assembling object names into dynamic SQL statements is to use [`QuoteName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to avoid problems with odd names, e.g. `New Table` with a space or reserved words like `From`.